# get H1 from divs and make a sidebar Link menu

Tags: jquery, html

i hope someone can point me in the right direction

On a existing html site , i have a page with a lot of divs , each div is a "news message"

i use pagination plugin on this page to show just 1 div at the time .

```
$("#newsmessages .news").quickpaginate({ perpage: 1, showcounter: true, pager : $("#nieuwsbericht_list_counter")  });
```

.

what i want to do is :

Get from every div the h1 put it in a list on the sidebar of the page and make it a link to the div .

This is the structure of the news messages:

```
  <div class"news">
  <h1>test</h1>
  <p>blablabla</p>
  </div>

  <div class"news">
  <h1>test1</h1>
  <p>blablabla</p>
  </div> 

  <div class"news">
  <h1>test2</h1>
  <p>blablabla</p>
  </div>    

<div/>
```

Is this possible with jquery  ?

this one is pulling my brains out for 3 days now

thnx

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Weston i have my sidebar with anchors ,

But when i click on a anchor nothing happens , i blame it on the pagination plugin , without this plugin the anchors work .

is there somebody with a solution for this i prefer a pagination plugininstead of scrolling down half an hour .

Thnx

Jeroen

Comment: what do you mean by *"make it a link to the div"*? do you mean doing a "anchor page jump"?

Comment: Yes thats it , so you get a list of anchors on the sidebar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the jQuery. It creates anchors in the news divs and puts links in a list in a sidebar div.

```
$(function() {
    var list = $('#sidebar ul');

    $(".news h1").each(function() {
        $(this).prepend('<a name="' + $(this).text() + '"></a>');
        $(list).append('<li><a href="#' + $(this).text() + '">' +  $(this).text() + '</a></li>');
    });
});
```

Here's the markup to go with it..

```
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="news">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>blablabla</p>
  </div>

  <div class="news">
    <h1>test1</h1>
    <p>blablabla</p>
  </div> 

  <div class="news">
    <h1>test2</h1>
    <p>blablabla</p>
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Weston thank you for this , it works , only problem left is wen i click one of the anchor links the requested message dont show , i think problem is in the pagination , do you also have a solution for that ?? thnx

Comment: I don't know that quickpaginate plugin. If it works by detaching/attaching DOM elements, then the #-links wont work. Somehow you will need to keep track of which page each news div is located on, and tell the paging thingy to switch to that page.

Answer (score 0):

Is it also possible to get all h1 and h2 into the sidebar link menu?
So the result can be like something as below:

- Title 1

  - Subtitle 1
  - Subtitle 2
- Title 2

  - Subtitle 3
  - Subtitle 4

⬇️With this kind of sample code⬇️

```
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
      <h2>Subtitle 1</h2>
      <p>Paragraph 1</p>
      <h2>Subtitle 2</h2>
      <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
      <h2>Subtitle 3</h2>
      <p>Paragraph 3</p>
      <h2>Subtitle 4</h2>
      <p>Paragraph 4</p>

</body>
```